# How to execute a print x amount of times?

Tags: java, for-loop

What I have:

```
public static void nestedForLoops() {
    int k = 5;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 5; j > i; j--) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
****1
***2
**3
*4
5
```

Trying to achieve:

```
****1
***22
**333
*4444
55555
```

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253792/stack-overflow-and-homework-questions

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
        if (5 - j >= i) {
            System.out.print("*");
        } else {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
           if (i <= 5 - j) {
               System.out.print("*");
            } else {
               System.out.print(i);
            }
        }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1,6,1):
    print "*" *(5-i),str(i) *i
```

Comment: Nice, but the question is tagged "Java" :))